# XML element must be present if specific attribute has value (not blank)

Tags: xml, xsd

I am working on something where I am supposed to include a particular XML element, only if value for some attribute is present (not blank).

For example:

```
<Students> 
  <Student> 
   <Name First = "Robin" Last = "Douglas"/> 
   <Address StreetApt="1234, Test St" City= "Kansas City" State = "MO" />    
   <Results Year="2015" Sem="Spring" GPA="3.5"/> 
  </Student> 
  <Student> 
   <Name First = "Sam" Last = "Evans"/> 
   <Address StreetApt="5678, Test Blvd" City= "Kansas City" State = "MO" /> 
   <Results Year="2015" Sem="Spring" GPA="3.9"> 
  </Student> 
  <Student> 
   <Name First = "Zack" Last = "Roberts"/> 
   <Address StreetApt="9078, Test Ave" City= "Kansas City" State = "MO" /> 
   <Results Year="2015" Sem="Spring" GPA=""> 
  </Student> 
</Students>
```

So, in above example, if you notice, `GPA` attribute from `<Results />` tag for the last student (named "Zack Roberts") contains no data. So, the requirement is if that particular attribute is empty, then I have to delete the entire `<Results />` tag for that particular student. Hence, the desired result will be:

```
<Students> 
  <Student> 
   <Name First = "Robin" Last = "Douglas"/> 
   <Address StreetApt="1234, Test St" City= "Kansas City" State = "MO" />    
   <Results Year="2015" Sem="Spring" GPA="3.5"/> 
  </Student> 
  <Student> 
   <Name First = "Sam" Last = "Evans"/> 
   <Address StreetApt="5678, Test Blvd" City= "Kansas City" State = "MO" /> 
   <Results Year="2015" Sem="Spring" GPA="3.9"> 
  </Student> 
  <Student> 
   <Name First = "Zack" Last = "Roberts"/> 
   <Address StreetApt="9078, Test Ave" City= "Kansas City" State = "MO" /> 
  </Student> 
</Students>
```

***Will you please tell me how to achieve this?*** I tried using `minOccurs`, `maxOccurs` in XSD, but then realized those things are not used for this purpose.

***My first priority is making some changes to XSD and trying to achieve the results. If not possible that way, then what is the other way possible?***

**Please note:** 
I have framed an example mentioned above. The real time piece of data I am working on has tag as follows:

```
<OrganizationId ImportAction="addModify" Type="GLN" Identifier="1234567890123" Primary="false" StartDate="2000-01-01"/>
```

The requirement mentions that if `Identifier` has 13-digit value (13-digit number) only then keep the `<OrganizationId>` tag. In all other cases, `<OrganizationId>` tag should not be present. In the Scribe job I am running to produce this XML, I am keeping all the 13-digit values, otherwise replacing those values with "". So, if you have any other solution for my particular case, then I welcome those too!

Comment: From what you've said so far, you can simply require that the value of `Results/@GPA` be of non-zero length.

Comment: Validation is different from manipulation. Just to make sure you are aware of this: you cannot "delete" an element while validating a document - it can only tell you whether it accepts the input document as a valid instance of the schema. Manipulation can be done e.g. with XSLT.

Comment: @kjhughes So, what you have mentioned can be achieved using XSD?

Comment: Simply make `@GPA` be required and non-empty.  I'll show you in an answer...

Comment: @MathiasMüller Müller, you have provided very useful information. Actually, I have framed an example over here. The real time piece of data I am working on will be provided in some time in my question only after I am done with editing it.

Comment: The updates to your question indicate a serious [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) here.

Comment: (1) Because of time wasted answering [Y when you really need help on X](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). (2) Because after several rounds, it's *still* not clear if you're looking to ***validate*** XML or ***change*** XML.  You ask about XSDs but you keep talking about changing XML.

Comment: Well, here is the answer to your comments: (1) I did not intend to (or neither did I) waste your time. I got valuable information from your comments and answer. Thanks for that. I needed help on Y only, which I got from you. Thinking further, I thought if I could directly get help on X (from which I had to come to Y because of the limited features of Scribe Insight tool which is being used to transfer the data to XML), it will be better. Hence the edit.

Comment: (2)  Really new to XSD's. Have worked on it just for few days (or hours?) Still, I mentioned that if it is not possible by XSD, I am open for other things. If you still feel like your time has been wasted, then I can't really help. My doubts were straightforward.

Comment: One last attempt before I throw in the towel, too. Please answer this basic question: a) Do you have an existing set of XML documents that you need to **change** (transformation / manipulation)? Or b) would you like to write rules for your XML documents, to **find out** which ones stick to the rules, without changing them (validation)?

Comment: I would like to 'create' XML document. It should follow XSD (again, mentioning my knowledge of XSD is limited and I am enhancing it). XML was getting created properly. But, one more requirement got added, which caused me to ask this question.

Comment: Then perhaps your question is about how to create an XML document that follows the rules of a specific, given XML Schema? Then, we would need to see the **code** that currently does that.

Comment: Hi Mathias, I have constructed new Q: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29807892/create-xml-using-xml-schema-with-scribe-job-xml-element-must-be-omitted-if-sp Please check, if you feel to do so.

Answer (score 1):

As Mathias mentioned, think not in terms of manipulation of the XML ("deletion") but in terms of validity.  You've stated your requirements as being that `Results` should not be present without a non-empty `@GPA`.   So, we make the GPA be required:

```
                  <xs:attribute name="GPA" use="required">
```

and be non-empty:

```
                    <xs:simpleType>
                      <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
                        <xs:minLength value="1"/>
                      </xs:restriction>
                    </xs:simpleType>
```

Altogether then:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <xs:element name="Students">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="Student" maxOccurs="unbounded">
          <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
              <xs:element name="Results" maxOccurs="unbounded">
                <xs:complexType>
                  <xs:sequence/>
                  <xs:attribute name="GPA" use="required">
                    <xs:simpleType>
                      <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
                        <xs:minLength value="1"/>
                      </xs:restriction>
                    </xs:simpleType>
                  </xs:attribute>
                </xs:complexType>
              </xs:element>
            </xs:sequence>
          </xs:complexType>
        </xs:element>
      </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

(Non-essential components omitted for clarity.  Their addition should be straightforward.)

Comment: Thank you very much, kjhughes! I have done some edit to my question at the end of it. If you can read that and may be suggest some other way too (if possible), that would be great.

Comment: Your update, despite our best efforts to dissuade you, is *still* using language of manipulation rather than language of validity.  If you fundamentally want to ***change*** XML, then use XSLT or some other language for processing XML.  If you fundamentally want to ***validate*** XML, use XSD or some other XML schema language.  Until you embrace this recommendation, your way forward will be unclear.